# How to set root path for static files in ServiceStack self-host

Tags: c#, .net, web, servicestack

All of the ServiceStack self-host examples serve static files from the same directory as the console or service executable assembly.

Is there a way to change the rooth path to something else?

When I set `Config.WebHostPhysicalPath` to a different path from within `AppHostHttpListenerBase.Configure`, my html file had to exist in both places for ServiceStack to return anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was wondering the same thing so I dug into the SS source and found an issue that prevents the `Config.WebHostPhysicalPath` from working with static files. You can read about it here: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/issues/352

**Update 2012-12-03**

My pull request for this issue has just been merged into ServiceStack/master.
https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/pull/357

Comment: Well, issue 352 appears to be gone from Github, so nothing to update to.